# I am losing data when going from constructor to main method in a different class. What is happening?

Tags: java, methods, constructor

````
```
  public class tuna 
  {
     private int hour;
     private int minute;
     private int second;

     // Constructor with 0 passed arguments
     public tuna()
     {
        this(0,0,0);
     }

     // Constructor with 1 passed arguments
     public tuna(int h)
     {
        this(h,0,0);
     }

     // Constructor with 2 passed arguments
     public tuna(int h, int m)
     {
        this(h,m,0);
     }

     // Constructor with 3 passed arguments
     public tuna(int h, int m, int s)
     {
        setTime(h,m,s);
     }

     // setTime method
     public void setTime(int h, int m, int s)
     {
        setHour(h);
        setMinute(m);
        setSecond(s);
     }

     /*----------Set methods----------*/
     public void setHour(int h) {hour = ( (h>=0 && h<24)?h : 0);}
     public void setMinute(int m) {hour = ( (m>=0 && m<60)?m : 0);}
     public void setSecond(int s) {hour = ( (s>=0 && s<60)?s : 0);}

     /*----------Get methods----------*/
     public int getHour() { 
        return hour;}
     public int getMinute() { 
        return minute;}
     public int getSecond() { 
        return second;}

     public String toMilitary()
     {
        return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", getHour(), getMinute(), getSecond());
     }
  }
```
````

Above is the class containing the constructors and methods and below is the class with the main function that actually calls on the constructors and methods.

I was making this simple program that displays the time and the exercise was showing that you can have multiple constructors with different amounts of parameters.  The only problem is when I am at the step of the constructor all the information is correct but when the debugger jumps from the constructor to the class it is being used in all the information is gone except this one line.  I think it has something to do with the way I set the constructors up but I can not figure out what I did wrong. Any help would be great. Thank you!

Here is the output that I get:

[image: What I am getting]

The desired output:

[image: Desired output]

And in case any of you recognize this exercise it is one of Bucky's Tutorials.
P.S. I normally would not post all the code but I literally have no idea what may or may not be pertinent to my problem.

```
class apples
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      tuna obj1 = new tuna(); // No parameter constructor
      tuna obj2 = new tuna(5); // 1 parameter constructor
      tuna obj3 = new tuna(5,13); // 2 parameter constructor
      tuna obj4 = new tuna(5,13,43); // 3 parameter constructor

      System.out.printf("%s\n", obj1.toMilitary());
      System.out.printf("%s\n", obj2.toMilitary());
      System.out.printf("%s\n", obj3.toMilitary());
      System.out.printf("%s\n", obj4.toMilitary());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning `hour` in all setters, while you should be setting `hour`, `minute` and `second`:

```
/*----------Set methods----------*/
public void setHour(int h) {hour = ( (h>=0 && h<24)?h : 0);}
public void setMinute(int m) {minute = ( (m>=0 && m<60)?m : 0);}
public void setSecond(int s) {second = ( (s>=0 && s<60)?s : 0);}
```

Comment: I feel so stupid right now man.  Sometimes all it takes is another set of eyes I guess.  Thank you!

Comment: @LawrenceGreer Maybe it was just a copy/paste problem... Who knows? :-) If my answer solved your problem, please don't forget to mark it as accepted. Thanks!